# Camtasia replacement for the Mac

Tags: macos, recording, software-rec, screen-capture, camtasia

On the PC, I use Camtasia to record various screencasts.  Is there something similar for the Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the [Mac version of Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasiamac/)?

Personally I prefer [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm).

Comment: Oh, dang, didn't see it.

Comment: ScreenFlow -> that's the guy! (I doesnt try Quicktime X yet)

Answer (score 4):

[Quicktime X](http://www.apple.com/macosx/technology/#quicktimex) can do this by default on Snow Leopard.

Comment: The Mac laptop I have to install this on is on Tiger.

Comment: How can you do this with Quicktime?

Answer (score 3):

Theres a myriad of these for Mac, but one that stands out for me is [Capture Me](http://www.chimoosoft.com/products/captureme/), it's free and open source. Not to mention **very** easy to use:

[image]

Features:

> - Globally floating capture window.
> - Record short MPEG-4 QuickTime movies.
> - Fast screen captures (uses OpenGL).
> - Ability to down scale captures (proportionally or not).
> - Save as PNG, JPEG, JPEG 2000, TIFF, or GIFF.
> - Adjustable translucency of capture window.
> - Several ways to adjust the size and position of the capture (move the
>     window, arrow keys, scroll wheel).
> - Nifty capture sound.
> - Options to auto-save to desktop, auto-copy to clipboard, etc.
> - Barest beginnings of AppleScript support.
> - Written with Cocoa - native to Mac OS X.
> - Universal binary - Intel, PPC native.

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime X will do screen recording, www.screentoaster.com is a free web-based screen recorder, there are lots of screen capture programs for the Mac, ScreenFlow is a very popuar one, but if you are used to Camtasia and like it, Camtasia has a Mac version.

Answer (score 1):

Why replacement when there's Camtasia for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty happy with [iShowU HD](http://store.shinywhitebox.com/ishowuhd/main.html) for $30 USD.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Snapz Pro](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/) for any Mac screencasting.