# Screen recording software on Mac?

Tags: mac, iphone, screencasts, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inexpensive, simple screen recording application for mac](https://superuser.com/questions/67474/inexpensive-simple-screen-recording-application-for-mac)

I want to show my iPhone simulator as video. Which software (FREE) is the Best one to record
video with minimum file size?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on superuser?

Comment: i could not understand pls..

Comment: @Jake: Maybe. They're trying to record the iPhone simulator to demonstrate their iPhone application, so it is somewhat related to programming.

Comment: @icktoofay: No, this definitely is a question for SuperUser.com

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/55086/camtasia-replacement-for-the-mac

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Screencast-O-Matic](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/) with good results.  Its free as long as your video is under 5 minutes.

Comment: @pkaeding +1 6+ years later, free is 15 mins now

Answer (score 0):

Though I know you're asking for a video recorder, you may find [SimFinger](http://news.atebits.com/post/197564349/not-your-average-iphone-screencast) useful. As for screen recording software, there's many choices.

This isn't an exhaustive list, but here are a few:

- [Snapz Pro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/)
- [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm)
- [iShowU HD](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowuhd/main.html)

None of which are free, but I don't know of any free ones.

Answer (score 0):

One up to Snapz, but I also really like Jing.