# screencasting tools for screencasts like vimcasts

Tags: macos, vim, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Camtasia replacement for the Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/55086/camtasia-replacement-for-the-mac)
>   https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording
>   [Inexpensive, simple screen recording application for mac](https://superuser.com/questions/67474/inexpensive-simple-screen-recording-application-for-mac)

I am on OSX.

Specifically, i want to insert the keystrokes being typed  into the screencast ( because in vi normal mode you dont see keystokes anywhere on the screen).

I looked at quicktime software but it doenst capture keystrokes.

Comment: Also, [look at the related questions on the tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture+mac)

Comment: I run [vimcasts.org](http://vimcasts.org/). I use [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/) on a mac.